# sphinxsearch merge indexes on different column names

Tags: sphinx

If i have indexA which returns `id, doc_id, attrA1, attrA2` and indexB with `id, group_id, attrB1, attrB2`, then is it possible to merge `indexer --merge indexA indexB`, so that the merged index will return `id, doc_id, attrA1, attrA2, attrB1, attrB2`? assuming that `doc_id` and `group_id` are equal, just with different column names

Answer (score 0):

No. Dont think indexer can do this directly.

The closest might be to directly edit the .sph files. Ie rename the attributes. eg could rename 'group_id' to 'doc_id' in the original, so will merge correctly.

Not sure what will the seperate attributes in only one or other index. I think only common attributes are preserved.